# Entity Framework: When will a variable be evaluated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I encountered strange behaviour with EF and IQueryable.

```
public IQueryable<foo> getFoo()  
{ 
  IQueryable<foo> query;
  string someVar = functies.getSomeInt().ToString();
  try
  {       
      query = from sTable in db.someTable
              from oTable in db.otherTable
              where sTable.Id == oTable.Id
              && sTable.Var == someVar
             select sTable;
   } catch {}
   return query;
}

public Test()
{
   var queryFoo =  getFoo();
   foreach(var foo in queryFoo)
   {
      //This works fine
   }
}
```

Above example will run just fine, but when you put the declaration of someVar inside the try block, EF cannot seem to compare sTable.Var with someVar.

```
public IQueryable<foo> getFoo()  
{ 
  IQueryable<foo> query;
  try
  {       
      string someVar = functies.getSomeInt().ToString();
      query = from sTable in db.someTable
              from oTable in db.otherTable
              where sTable.Id == oTable.Id
              && sTable.Var == someVar
             select sTable;
   } catch {}
   return query;
}

public Test()
{
   var queryFoo =  getFoo();
   foreach(var foo in queryFoo)
   {
      //This doesn't work
      //unable to create constant value of type 'foo'
   }
}
```

This results in an "Unable to create a constant value of type 'foo'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Is there any logical explanation to why EF is behaving this way? 
I really don't understand the difference, it probably has something to do with the scope of the variable. But it still seems strange.

What research gotten me so far (so if I follow below examples, someVar isn't local when nested further down???):

> Local variables, such as the orderID variable in the following
>   example, are evaluated on the client.

```
int orderID = 51987;

IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader> salesInfo =
from s in context.SalesOrderHeaders
where s.SalesOrderID == orderID
select s;
```

Also

> Method parameters are also evaluated on the client. The orderID parameter passed into the MethodParameterExample method.

```
public static void MethodParameterExample(int orderID)
{
 using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
 {

    IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader> salesInfo =
        from s in context.SalesOrderHeaders
        where s.SalesOrderID == orderID
        select s;                

    foreach (SalesOrderHeader sale in salesInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OrderID: {0}, Total due: {1}", sale.SalesOrderID, sale.TotalDue);
    }
 }
}
```

[Literals and Parametesr on the Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx)

Not altered:

```
public IQueryable<klassen> getKlassenPerGebruiker(Db.Models.gebruiker gbr)
{
 // Connectie met de database maken.
 var db = new Datastore.Db.Models.dataContext(); //of type DbContext
 IQueryable<klassen> query;

 try
 {
    string jaar = functies.getHuidigStartJaar().ToString();
    query = from klas in db.klassens
            from kpg in db.klassenpergebruikers
            from sj in db.schooljaars
            where kpg.Klassen_id == klas.Id
               && kpg.Gebruikers_id == gbr.Id
               && sj.Id == klas.Schooljaar_id
               && sj.Start == jaar
               && kpg.School_id == gbr.School_id
               orderby klas.Naam
            select klas;
 }
 catch
 {
   query = null;
 }
}
```

calling function;

```
 IQueryable qklassen = gs.getKlassenPerGebruiker((user) Session["user"]);

            if (qklassen != null)
            {
                foreach (klassen klas in qklassen)
                {
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please learn to think like a programmer. Don't say "EF cannot seem to resolve someVar". Say what happened (behavior and/or error messages).

Comment: What you have now cannot possibly run fine. If your query construction throws an exception, `query` is left uninitialised, and the C# compiler will detect that possibility and reject your `return query;` statement. Show some actual working code, as well as non-working code where the *only* change between that and the working code is what you're asking about.

Comment: @JonathanWood Updated the post. I am quite new with posting questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: My strong feeling is that these examples don't fully represent your real code. This shouldn't make any difference. In *reality* you probably have some method returning a "`Foo`" that is evaluated either before or during execution of the `IQueryable`.

Comment: Hey @GertArnold, this example can not be more close to what I actually do. There are some more tables involved (joins 4 the win). I want to point out that I do not return a ""Foo" object, but the IQueryable thats evaluated outside the getFoo() method. I can create a testproject and share it which invokes this behaviour.

Comment: You can fix the whole thing by returning IEnumerable<foo> instead of IQueryable<foo>.

Comment: @joordan831 I can fix this in many ways, personally I really don't like db entities being exposed to the businesslogic layer. I did not create the project, but I do have to adapt some code. Putting the someVar declaration outside the try scope is enough for the project at hand. But I really want to understand the behaviour as it seems illogical for my perspective.

Comment: @GertArnold thanx for the tip about the action, just tried it out and it is indeed not the closure. As your example with action worked. 
I updating with the real code if that is going to help

Comment: Is this also IQueryable? functies.getHuidigStartJaar()

Comment: @joordan831 No this just returns an int.  DateTime.Now.Year or  DateTime.Now.Year - 1 depending on the month

Comment: Take `gbr.Id` and `gbr.School_id` out of the query and use two int variables instead.

Comment: @GertArnold okay, before I do that, what difference does it make? One is an db entity which is evaluated by the server (if i get the terminology). If you make them two int variables, they are evaluated by the client are they not? To be clear, I do not need a solution as placing the variable outside the try block works perfectly. I just need to understand why it happens.

Comment: If you hardcode the year value for "jaar," would it work either in or outside the try block?

Comment: You may want to compare the expression tree of the IQueryable between each, or look at the IL to compare.

Comment: It got too late for me... I don't see why your query would raise the exception. It would if you had something like `kpg.Gebruiker == gbr`. But let's get it settled now that it's got nothing to do with where the `jaar` variable is initialized, because it is captured. `query` is an expression tree that is translated into SQL by the client. During this translation *each involved variable* is evaluated, *client-side*. The database only receives SQL and returns a tabular result set.

Comment: @joordan831 If I hardcoded the year variable, it always seems to work.

Comment: Can we see that function, functies.getHuidigStartJaar()? Also, is sj.Start a string data type?

Answer (score 1):

It is evaluated when you evaluate it. Which happens when you materialize the query (ToArray,FirstOrDefault etc.). You return the query - and here is the problem.

Comment: To expand on TomTom's excellent answer, @yowlsmie you should do some research into "variable scope".

Comment: Hey TomTom, does that mean that the query is executed against the db when I return the queryable?

To expand on my confusion, I can loop over the returned Queryable when someVar is also already destroyed.

Comment: @SamAxe As far as I know, if I return IQueryable to another function, someVar is already destroyed. But EF doesn't have any problem with that.   Am I missing something?

Comment: @yowslymie Yes, you're missing the fact that when you close over a variable in a lambda *that variable cannot be destroyed* until there are no longer any references to it.  A variable must always live for as long as there is code that could run that would access it, and since your program still has code that could run that would access it after returning, that variable cannot be cleaned up when the method returns.

Comment: @Servy Okay, I do get that, but in that case my two examples should have the same result. As both lambda's have a reference to someVar. The only thing that changed is the scope. Excuse me if I'm being a total newbie, but I still don't fully grasp the difference between the two examples.

Comment: @yowslymie As you've already been told, the code you've provided cannot possibly cause the behavior you describe.  You have not accurately represented the use cases that generated this behavior (or aren't accurately describing the behavior of the code that you have).  You are quite correct that changing the scope of the local as you've done wouldn't change the behavior of the code as described in the question.

Comment: @Servy As I replied to GertArnold I can make you a testing project that I'm gladly share that invokes this exact behaviour. But this is as close as it gets, the only thing that I have changed is the query, as I didn't want to bother you guys with 5 joins.

Comment: @yowslymie It's absolutely appropriate to make a simplified version of the code when posting to SO, you just need to make sure that the simplified version *still replicates the problem*.